# Gravity Forms field ID $entry not working

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

So my script is simple right now just to test out the $entry field id's.

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_3", "set_post_content", 10, 2);
function set_post_content($entry, $form){
$subject = $entry["28"] . 'Applied as: ' . $entry["2"];
 mail( $emailremoved, $subject, $message);
}
```

Right now entry 28 is a dropdown, this one returns the selected value.

Entry 2 is the name field with split first and last. This returns nothing. Ive also tried $entry["2.1"] and get nothing.

Entry 34 (not added) is a multi checkbox. This value is not echoed out either.

This is a multipage form, but that shouldnt matter.

Any ideas why the values are not returning? They are saving to the form entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug you should print what's in $entry.

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($entry,true) . '</pre>';
die();//You may need to kill the script to view..
```

Or email to yourself in your current mail function.

```
$message = '<pre>' . print_r($entry,true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was so fixated on the single inputs that I didn't think to print them all. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware the normal and extended format name fields are constructed using multiple inputs, for this reason you also need to include the last digit from the input id in the key.

```
$entry['2.2'] // prefix
$entry['2.3'] // first
$entry['2.6'] // last
$entry['2.8'] // suffix
```